# How to get rid of vertice on the same high?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

I have a question. How could I get rid of the vertice that is in the same high as the other vertice?
I'm using booelan tools, but it's didn't work, because of these vertices. Thanks you.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems you might have overlapping geometry, so you would have to solve that somehow if you wanted to have one piece of geometry. If the vertices are between edges on the same connected plane with nice non-overlapping topology, you can select all flat connected faces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> when you have one of them selected and then just press <kbd>f</kbd> for Make Face:

[image]

You could remove vertices from separate pieces of the mesh that you have there. If you wanted to join them into one piece, that is another question. I believe there is no easy clean way to do this, I would just remodel the whole thing as one if that is needed. Booleans might not work nicely if you have overlapping surfaces.

Comment: Good to note that the "Select linked flat faces" shortcut (Ctrl Alt Shift F) doesn't exist in 2.8. If you need it, you can create it this way in the user preferences → input → 3D view → mesh: https://i.imgur.com/BBIhbp0.png
Otherwise, you can find it in the select sub menu https://i.imgur.com/olKUK6u.png or via the search function.

Comment: 2.8 is still beta. I will start using it in the answers as soon as it is released. At the moment it is still risky to spend time on that. We might just be leaving this info for people browsing the web to find, but it might be irrelevant or wrong in a couple of months. It may still change in 2.8.

Comment: Oh and by the way, it's a lot easier to set the shortcut just by right-clicking the function in the menu and choosing Change Shortcut.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that one x)

Comment: Thanks you for our quick answer. Well, I've tried ctrl+alt+shift+f and this is not working. I think your suggestion is right, I have to remodel it. I hope blender will update a tools to fix it one day. And Thanks again for your answer:)

Comment: Blender has all the adequate tools - no need to update. You just need to learn to use them. L0Lock indicated that the shortcut is not currently in 2.80 version that is still in beta stage of development and should only be used for testing. 2.7 versions have the shortcut by default. You need to select one face and hit ctrl+alt+shift+f to select connected flat faces. There is also a tool for selecting all faces on the same plane - shif+g -> Co-planar. You can change it's threshold in the T panel or F6 menu (this is for versions 2.7x again). That will not care if faces are connected or not.